# What is a proper command to build TensorFlow Lite C++ API for macOS?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am successfully using TensorFlow Lite C++ API for Android, which is built on macOS.

Now I want to try it for macOS since TensorFlow Lite support Metal delegate (for iOS?).
You know, TensorFlow itself has stopped supporting GPU on macOS several years ago.

What is a proper command to build TensorFlow Lite C++ API for macOS?

For Android,

```
bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64 //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

I have no idea about config for macOS.
But I think that it should exist because tflite_runtime package exists for macOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following?

```
bazel build -c opt --cpu=darwin //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

This will build the `.so` file for x86_64 macos. That being said, the Metal delegate is probably not included in the final binary, as Metal delegate is specifically targeting iOS.

Comment: Thank you! I successfully compiled TFLite for macOS according to your comment. And I also compiled tensorflow_lite_gpu_framework for macOS though I have no idea if it works on macOS.

Comment: hi, can we have C api by using this build? Thanks!